# How to display web service errors using toast (Android)

Tags: java, android, web-services

How to handle web service errors such as 500 or 404 and display them inside a toast in android, here is some of my code below:

```
public String readJSONFeed(String URL) {

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);

    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }

            inputStream.close();
        } else if (statusCode == 500) {

                      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                                     "JSON - Failed to download file", 
                                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("readJSONFeed", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Once I have run this code and experience an error such as 500 the toast does not display

Comment: And your question is ...?

Comment: How to use toast in displaying web service errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "JSON - Failed to download file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
});
```

Problem Solved

Answer (score 0):

simply append ur status code in toast thats all

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"JSON - Failed to download file"+status_code,
                                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: are you getting and erros?in logcat?